# Setting up a Ruby on Rails environment, made a change with RVM now Rails won't work.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup RoR on my system. I've used the instructions here http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

I'm getting stuck because I was finally able to get Rails installed, but after I set the Ruby version, it won't detect rails anymore

```
CJs-MacBook-Air:~ cjwheelock$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.1
CJs-MacBook-Air:~ cjwheelock$ rvm use ruby-2.0.0@learn-rails --create
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/cjwheelock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin'          is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353'.
```

Using /Users/cjwheelock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 with gemset learn-rails

```
CJs-MacBook-Air:~ cjwheelock$ rails -v
```

Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

```
CJs-MacBook-Air:~ cjwheelock$ gem install rails
```

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully my formatting is readable, its my first time posting here.

Thank you.

Comment: how did u set ur ruby version?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` ?

Answer (score 0):

First restart terminal.

```
# rvm list
# rvm use 2.0.0-pXXX --default (XXX is the biggest number)
# gem install rails
```

If you will have some problems, install requirements(openssl, etc... : type below for more infomation)

```
# rvm requirements
```

install deb packages

```
# sudo apt-get install blaaaaaaaa
```

reinstall ruby 2.0.0

```
# rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

and try first step.
Good Luck